# Android application login with google account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

I am developing application in which user want to log in with their g mail username and password 
,how can i do this and where is sample code and simple tutorial for this.
I already looked many tutorial but i cant understand it properly and may tutorial are very complex.I am trying [like](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode) this tutorial but it is not run properly mean not getting token
and not finish WebActivity to coming to first activity.

Answer (score 2):

The blog I used a couple of years ago was Nick's blog

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

It's fairly straight forward. There are two steps

1. Get Authtoken from the Android Authentication Manager
2. Make a http(s) request to your appengine app (/_ah/login end point) with the authtoken which will respond with a cookie. Read the cookie and use for all future requests to appengine.

You can follow the blog directly, but since the blog was written Google have made a [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) available that simplifies step 1. of getting the auth token. This class however requires the play framework installed.